# I have problems with shared_ptr. Why does this code throw SEGV?

Tags: c++

Why does this code throw SEGV? I have two simple structures with one field shared ptr. I get "SEGV on unknown address".

```
struct B;

struct A {
    shared_ptr<B> p;
};

struct B {
    shared_ptr<A> p;
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<A> p1;
    shared_ptr<B> p2;
    p2->p = p1; // falls here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, what does `p2` point to?

Comment: Your two structures set things up for an infinite loop, where the reference counters of the `p` members will never go down to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does this code throw SEGV?

Because default initialised shared pointer points to null. And you attempt to access non-existing object through the null pointer here:

```
p2->p = p1; // falls here
  ^
```

Answer (score 6):

You never make `p2` actually point somewhere. It's like having

```
B* p2 = nullptr;
p2->p = p1;
```

You need to make `p2` point somewhere valid:

```
auto p2 = std::make_shared<B>();
```

Answer (score 4):

p2 is pointer(in this case nullptr) but is not object, you need initialize pointers to new objects;

```
{
  shared_ptr<A> p1(new A); // or std::make_shared()
  shared_ptr<B> p2(new B);
}
```

after this you can access to members of object by pointer.

Recommendation: use weak_ptr for pointers which refer one to one for avoid fault on object destruction.